# Local Storage is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, themes, local-storage

I am trying to use themes for one of my websites wherein the user can select the theme color dynamically. Once the theme color is stored, it has to retain the color value and has to get updated in other pages too. But, the color does not get updated in my other pages

```
<body>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Theme <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">red</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">green</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">blue</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a href="local-storage.html">next page</a>
</body>
```

AND MY JQUERY CODE IS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function () {
    var color=($(this).text());
    if(color == "red"){
    $('body').css("background-color","red");
    }
    else
    if(color == "green"){
    $('body').css("background-color","green");
    }
    else
    if(color == "blue"){
    $('body').css("background-color","blue");
    }
    localStorage.setItem("value", color);
});


var name = localStorage.getItem("value");
$('body').css("background-color","name");
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove apostrophe when using the variable name:

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("value");
$('body').css("background-color",name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("value");
$('body').css("background-color", name);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5b7L12n/)